# Wait for image to be loaded after AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I searched for a solution in below thread, but I'm using a different approach
[Javascript - wait images to be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104346/javascript-wait-images-to-be-loaded)

Basically: 1) I do an AJAX request and wait for the answer. 2) The answer is the URL to a picture, and I put this picture, overriding the previous one. This works:

```
//ON AJAX RESPONSE
{
    //Here I get var newPicture from AJAX.
    $.("#newPic").setAttribute("src", newPicture); //This is working

    openCrop(); //This is my function that will trigger jCrop in the picture
}
```

openCrop() works in localhost, since image loads immediately. But does not works online. since I have to wait until the image is loaded, and then trigger function openCrop().

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan He did mention $.("newPic").

Comment: @choz then will `setAttribute` work?

Comment: sorry for the "setAttribute". What I meant is I am able to change the picture ;) Thanks for the comment, though.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan It would, why not?

Comment: @choz: [`setAttribute` is not a jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/?s=setAttribute), it's a DOM method.

Comment: @RodrigoKravetz: We are not able to tell the difference between mistakes in your actual code and the code you posted here, because all we know is what you posted here. So please don't introduce any mistake that could distract from the actual problem.

Comment: Also, I hope you realize that the answers you got here are basically the same as in the linked question. You have to listen to the load event of the image.

Comment: "What to do" is different of "how to do", though. And this guys helped me on this. I appreciate their help. I just came back to coding since I've been quite busy in a peacekeeping mission. Nevertheless, I appreciate your comments and wish you all the best. Let's work.

Comment: @FelixKling Im not talking about the setAttribute, I said "$."... its a dollar sign yawww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you have to use the `load()`-function which listens to the onload event.

```
$('#newPic').load( function(){
    openCrop();
});
```

If you are doing vanilla JS you can do following:

```
var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'newsrc.png';
    img.onload = function(){
        openCrop();
    };
```

This way it waits till the Image has loaded and then do the action.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for this:

```
$("#newPic").setAttribute("src", newPicture).load(openCrop);
```

This will call your `openCrop` function when the image is done loading.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzL980jt/)

Comment: Think he would have to create new `$('<img />')` element and there set the `src` and wait for browser to load it. Only after that the `$("#newPic")` may get new `src`. Setting the attribute the way you proposed will cause client to practically see the image is missing. I would put an AJAX loader image meanwhile.

Comment: If `newPic` is the `<img/>` this will be enough.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't we set the `load` event before we set the image source? Can it happen the image is already loaded before we set the event? Probably correct sequence would be `$("#newPic").load(openCrop).attr("src", newPicture);`

Answer (score 1):

you could use onload event of image, as:

```
$.("#newPic").setAttribute("src", newPicture);
$.("#newPic").onload(function() {
    //image loaded, call the function
    openCrop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
    pics = 0;
    
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    
    $('img').load( function(){
    pics++;
    if(pics > 9){
     console.log("ten pictures loaded")
     openCrop()
    }
    });
    
    });
```

I think that a `.load` event needs to be wrapped in something like an `.ajaxComplete` event. jQuery won't understand what is going on unless the elements exist on the page. The standard `$(document).ready` event is used for the same reason.